# Tailwind - How to change div background when checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to change the background color of the wrapping div when the inner input is checked. This is my current code:

```html
      <div
        class="flex items-center pl-4 border border-gray-200 rounded-xl"
      >
        <input
          id="bordered-checkbox-1"
          type="checkbox"
          value=""
          name="bordered-checkbox"
          class="w-5 h-5 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-0"
        />
        <label
          for="bordered-checkbox-1"
          class="w-full py-4 ml-2 text-sm"
          >Default radio</label
        >
      </div>
```

I tried to add the peer class to the input but its only affecting the sibling elements not the parent and the group class is not working because its not recognizing when the checkbox is checked.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can only target sibling elements with `peer`. If you want to target parent with css only you can use new css pseudo-selector `:has` selector.

Something like this:

```
<div class="input-wrapper flex items-center rounded-xl border border-gray-200 pl-4">
  <input id="bordered-checkbox-1" type="checkbox" value="" name="bordered-checkbox" class="h-5 w-5 rounded border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 text-blue-600 focus:ring-0" />
  <label for="bordered-checkbox-1" class="ml-2 w-full py-4 text-sm">Default radio</label>
</div>
```

css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .input-wrapper:has(input:checked) {
    @apply border-blue-800 bg-blue-400 text-blue-800;
  }
}
```

**Note**: `:has` has limited support, not all browser support this. Check which [browser has support](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

[Tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Hxc7LXbRWG?file=css)